# NextJS Link Calling Function and Redirect Rather than Route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a link in my NextJS application that calls an API endpoint to log out a user and end their session, but I can't figure out the right pattern to do this. I would ideally like users to be able to do this by accessing `/app/logout/`. At the moment I am using NextJS links with an `onClick` that prevents the default behavior and triggers the API, but currently it is looking past the onClick and continuing with the router, leading the user to a `404` because /app/logout does not exist. Is there a better approach to this?

Here is my code:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const signOut = (e) => {
        const router = useRouter()
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('/api/auth/logout/')
        .then(() => router.push('/'))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.request)
            console.log(err.message)
        })
    }

const Links = () => (
    <ul className="nav-links inline-flex justify-center">
        <li className="mx-5">
            <Link href="/app/feed/"><a>Feed</a></Link>
        </li>
        <li className="mx-5">
            <Link href="/app/profile/"><a>Profile</a></Link>
        </li>
        <li className="mx-5">
            <Link href="/app/logout/" onClick={ signOut }><a>Log Out</a></Link>
        </li>
    </ul>
)

export default Links;
```

Backend Express.js Server Route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/*      /api/auth/logout/      */
router.route('/logout/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        console.log('/api/auth/logout/ CALLED')
        req.logout();
        req.session.destroy();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently ran into the same issue. Found this simply worked without using a `Link`.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const LogoutButton = () => {

    const router = useRouter();
    
    const handleLogout = async () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        await axios.post("/api/user/logout");
        router.push("/");
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={handleLogout}><u>Logout</u></button>
    );
};
```